# Is the Russian word «рейс» related to the German word "Reise"?

Tags: этимология, other-languages, заимствования

Both words have similar meanings and they both seem phonetically similar as well. So, it seems to me that there's the possibility of some relation between the two words.

I'm curious if one of the words is derived or borrowed from the other, or if perhaps they share some common "ancestor" word borrowed from a completely different language.

According to [en.wiktionary.org/wiki/рейс](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81#Etymology), the Russian `рейс` is derived from `reis` in Dutch.

And, according to [en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reis#Dutch), the Dutch word appears to have been borrowed from Estonian (at least that was how I vaguely understood the page). And, subsequently the Estonian word was derived from the German `Reise`.

So, my preliminary research has lead me to believe that the Russian `рейс` is indirectly derived from the German `Reise`. Although, I'm not really confident that this is entirely accurate.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't say that the Dutch word "reis" is borrowed from Estonian, you are wrong. That's a word found in many Germanic languages, even in Gothic.

Comment: @YellowSky Yes, you're right. I inferred that based upon the way the information was presented on the page. I'll admit that it was a bit of a stretch though. Also, the lack of any solid connection there was what really prompted me to ask this question in the first place.

Comment: Basically, the majority of Russian navy and sailing terms are borrowed from Dutch, dozens and dozens of them, but I don't know much about Germans being skillful sailors or about German sailing terms in Russian. Besides, the Dutch word sounds exactly like the Russian one, and the German one sounds differently. Why do you doubt it that "рейс" is a borrowing from Dutch?

Comment: @YellowSky I'm sorry, I should have been more clear; I was unsure about the link to the Estonian word, not the Dutch word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these words are cognates.

According to etymolgical dictionaries, the Russian word **рейс** wasn't borrowed from German but rather from Dutch where it is known as **reis**.

Both the German **Reise** and the Dutch **reis** have the same origin and are derived from Old High German [*reisa*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reisen#Etymology_1) (“a setting out, expedtion, journey”) from Proto-Germanic *raisōną (“to set out, depart”), from Proto-Indo-European *rei- (“to rise, arise”).

This word has cognates in many languages:

> North Frisian *reyse* (“travel, expedition”), Danish *rejse* (“journey,
>   trip, travel”), Swedish *resa* (“trip, journey”), Old English *rāsian*
>   (“to explore, examine, research”).

Comment: could these be related to the english word "arrive"?